# Как (в каком формате) сохранять большую таблицу

Tags: python, строки, excel, таблицы

Имеется код на питоне, который получает данные с файла, примерно 14 миллионов строк, и надо его сохранять как таблицу. Каким образом его лучше сделать? В идеале сохранять на экселе, но там максимум чуть более миллиона строк можно сохранять.

Comment: Человечество не зря изобрело базы данных.

Comment: если есть возможность использовать какой-нибудь символ в качестве разделителя, то можно сохранить как csv файл (по умолчанию используется запятая), фактически это текстовой файл в котором данные в строках разделяются символом-разделителем.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример данных из файла и пример данных из таблицы.

Comment: Да в чём угодно, вариантов полно. Вопрос - что вы потом хотите делать с этой таблицей и каковы приоритеты? Например, по скорости сохранения и чтения хорош формат `feather`.